# Django Rest Framework Serializer Method Calling

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm new at Django Rest Framework and I wonder how methods create and update are called inside a ModelSerializer Class.

What I understand is that create and update methods are automatically triggered when a POST or PUT request is sent. Is there a way to call a new function, like say_hello()?

Here's an example. I want to call method **say_hello()** when I hit a **PUT Request**

```
    class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        """Serializer for the users object"""
    
        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = "__all__"
    
        def create(self, validated_data):
            """Create a new user with encrypted password and return it"""
            return get_user_model().objects.create_user(**validated_data)
    
        def update(self, instance, validated_data):
            """Update an user, setting the password and return it"""
            password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
            user = super().update(instance, validated_data)
    
            if password:
                user.set_password(password)
                user.save()
    
            return user
    
        def say_hello(self, validated_data):
            print(validated_data)
            return "Hello you"
```

Comment: You can call the `say_hello(...)` method from the `update()` method, right?

Comment: Sure, but how can I call a different method instead update, create?

Comment: This happens in the views. It really dipense what kind of view you are using. In generic views you can change this behavior in `perform_create(self, serializer)` and `perform_update(self, serializer)`.

Answer (score 1):

To call a different method than the update method, you need to overwrite your serializer's def save() method:

```
def save(self, **kwargs):
    validated_data = [
        {**attrs, **kwargs} for attrs in self.validated_data
    ]

    if self.instance is not None:
        self.instance = self.say_hello(self.instance, validated_data)
        assert self.instance is not None, (
            '`update()` did not return an object instance.'
        )
    else:
        self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
        assert self.instance is not None, (
            '`create()` did not return an object instance.'
        )

    return self.instance
```

You can check out the Django Rest Framework default implementation [here](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/96993d817a6af9c037ece7253cfae49efc814f49/rest_framework/serializers.py#L684).

But what you rather might want to do, is to modify your ViewSet, by overwriting the def perform_update() method:

```
def perform_update(self, serializer):
    serializer.say_hello()
```